# Weird fade transition that is not wanted with fullpage.js and midnight.js

Tags: fullpage.js, fading

I have a wordpress site I'm creating using fullpage.js and using the midnight.js with jquery. When I scroll down the logo changes color but it is delayed. for the life of me I cannot figure out where the delay is coming from. Here is the testing site. https://trailheadnc.org

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how midnight.js works, but I know how fullPage.js does :)

Probably the easiest fix you'll be able to find is using the fullPage.js option `scrollBar:true`.

That should make the site act as any other site, firing the scroll event.

Dealing with css3 transformations might be the cause of midnight.js not working properly. Browsers still have it difficult to achieve certain things and might require the transformations to end to apply the changes.

If you really do not want to show the scroll bar by using `scrollBar:true`, then you can try using `css3:false`. This way fullPage.js will change the top property of the site and you might not encounter the same issues you have when dealing with 3d transformations.